# Lost profile and changes on my Cloud Service VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

We have a cloud service our in Azure-Land.  Whenever it comes time to push a new code release, we publish the files to a local disk, remote into the cloud service's VM instance and "copy\paste" the files into the appropriate IIS root, and we've been doing it this way for about a year now.

Today I logged into my VM to publish some changes and noticed 2 odd things:

1. My desktop profile was gone. Any files\folders I had stored from previous releases and such were missing, all I had was a recycling bin and nothing more
2. My web.config changes from previous releases were gone.  This item in particular was the scariest aspect to me.. I had added some changes to my config over the past month, and today my config was as if it was never touched.

Does anything happen with Azure storage, etc. with these cloud service instances? Do apps migrate over time? Does it have anything to do with windows update schedules? Has anyone else noticed this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes made directly on Cloud Services VMs aren't persistent. refer to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/10/05/windows-azure-disk-partition-preservation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @JuneT, thats definately helpful.  So my next question has to be.. how do I indirectly make changes to my cloud service VM so it persists?  In particular, Im talking about config file changes and such, do I need to do a "publish to windows azure" in visual studio to ensure my changes stick?

Comment: have a look at this link on storing your configuration out of the deployment package: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589803.aspx